# `org-export-to-html` does not export ANSI colors

Tags: org-mode

**The Issue**

after running `org-export-to-html` on the following code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :exports both :results output
  echo -e "\e[0;31mOUTPUT\e[0m"
#+END_SRC
```

OUTPUT is exported in black color

**Desired output**

OUTPUT being exported in red color

---

**Proposed solution**

The following code exports the output to html using ([aha](https://github.com/theZiz/aha))

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :exports both :results output html
  echo -e "\e[0;31mOUTPUT\e[0m" | aha
#+END_SRC
```

**The issue with the proposed solution**

The initial command is just `echo -e "\e[0;31mOUTPUT\e[0m"` not `echo -e "\e[0;31mOUTPUT\e[0m" | aha`